# How to periodically refresh R-Shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

I have an R-Shiny application, and inside the server function I fetch data to use within. Because I want to re-fetch this data after every 20 seconds or so, I have added the following function at the end of the server function as below:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # Process data
    # ...

    # Reload data

    counter <- reactiveVal(0)

    observe({
      invalidateLater(20000, session)
      if (counter() > 0) {
        session$reload()
      } else{
        counter(isolate(counter()) + 1)
      }
    })

}
```

The problem is that session reload seems to be called immediately the server function has finished execution, that is, way quicker that indicated in the by `invalidateLater()`.

Is there a way to make this work, would be grateful for any other approach.

Comment: Not sure to understand, but does `if(isolate(counter()) > 0)` solve the problem?

Comment: use a cron on a separate `updateData.R` script?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent thanks a lot! That just worked like a charm.

Comment: @cory will look at that approach. Thanks.